# Spacemacs command as meta not working

Tags: macos, emacs, spacemacs

I use spacemacs, and I've tried putting the following in my `personal.el`

`(setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil
      mac-command-key-is-meta t
      mac-command-modifier 'meta
      mac-option-modifier 'none)
(setq ns-command-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-option-modifier 'none)
(setq ns-function-modifier 'none)
(setq mac-pass-command-to-system nil)`

But I'm still stuck with option as meta. Is there anything else I need to do?

I used prelude before this and was able to set this up

Comment: Not familiar with spacemacs, however, the [Quick Start Guide](http://spacemacs.org/doc/QUICK_START.html) for spacemacs does not mention `personal.el`.  Check out that link for initialisation options.

Comment: I think if you look in ~/.spacemacs, you'll find sections where it's appropriate for you to provide personal settings (look particularly at dotspacemacs/user-config).

Comment: I have tons of personal settings, that isn't the issue; it's specifically one this configuration that isn't working.

Comment: Are other settings from personal.el being honored?

Comment: Yes they are (example, setting `M-g` to `goto-line`)